# Is there a way to use H2O partial_plot function to create partial dependent plot for multi-classification problem?

Tags: h2o

I have used the H2O function "partial_plot" to created the partial dependent plot for binary problem. But when I try to use the same function apply to multi-classification problem, it fails with error message.

```
failed with an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: unimplemented
```

Does that mean we cannot use partial_plot function to run multi-classification problem? maybe some plot like the [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192897/interpretation-of-partial-dependence-plots-for-multinomial-gbm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 3.24.0.4 it isn't implemented (as the error indicates), but I've created a JIRA ticket [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-6250) where you can track the progress of this feature request and add comments if needed.